# iOS Apptentive SDK - NSInvalidArgumentException from `[NSManagedObject setup]`

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmanagedobject, apptentive

i'm new in iOS programminng. I want to use feedback system with Apptentive SDK in my first App.
There is no errors while compiling, but when it start to make connection with Apptentive server, i get this error message:

```
2013-07-11 15:32:19.438 wishes[11015:c07] Loading ATWebClient_Metrics_Bootstrap
2013-07-11 15:32:19.438 wishes[11015:c07] Loading ATWebClient_SurveyAdditions_Bootstrap
2013-07-11 15:32:19.439 wishes[11015:c07] Loading ATURLConnection_Private_Bootstrap
2013-07-11 15:32:19.439 wishes[11015:c07] Loading ATWebClient_Private_Bootstrap
2013-07-11 15:32:19.439 wishes[11015:c07] Loading ATWebClient_MessageCenter_Bootstrap
2013-07-11 15:32:19.440 wishes[11015:c07] Loading ATToolbar_Bootstrap
2013-07-11 15:32:19.442 wishes[11015:1303] [info] Setting up data manager
2013-07-11 15:32:19.598 wishes[11015:1d03] [info] Creating conversation
**2013-07-11 15:32:19.616 wishes[11015:c07] -[NSManagedObject setup]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa060110
2013-07-11 15:32:19.618 wishes[11015:c07] ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject setup]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa060110'
** First throw call stack:
(0x2ef4012 0x23a0e7e 0x2f7f4bd 0x2ee3bbc 0x2ee394e 0xbc347 0xbc29f 0xf8f5b3 0x2eb3376 0x2eb2e06 0x2e9aa82 0x2e99f44 0x2e99e1b 0x2e4e7e3 0x2e4e668 0x26bffc 0x2afd 0x2a25)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception**
```

While searching forums i found, that it could be a problem of CoreData, that Apptentive SDK uses, but as i write, i'm new in iOS developing, so i didn't use CodeData till now.

The code to start connection:

```
ATConnect *connection = [ATConnect sharedConnection];
connection.apiKey = @"myApiKey";
[connection presentMessageCenterFromViewController:self];
```

When i uncomment a line with apiKey assign, there is no error.

Please help me if You can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Apptentive uses categories, like `setup` on `NSManagedObject`, but in your system those categories are not getting loaded. This issue is a somewhat difficult issue to understand, and the solution is murky and dependent on the version of Xcode you are using.

To force categories to load using a sledge hammer, add this to your "Other linker flags":

```
-all_load
```

If that works, then try this much better solution (changing "" to its real name:

```
-force_load $(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR)/<apptentive_library_name>.a
```

If that works, then you can try just using this flag:

```
-ObjC
```

If you search on this site for the terms "all_load", "force_load", and "-ObjC" you'll find oodles of posts.

Comment: Thank You, Your solution works. "-ObjC" is just fine.
You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Apptentive project settings guide](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios), we recommend the following "Other Linker Flags:

Target > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags:

```
-ObjC -all_load
```